# ERROR: Unsupported PIVOT column type: text

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot, sql-server-2019

I'm trying to perform a PIVOT but getting an error. I'm trying to see which patients have more than one Interval session. The column is a text type. I attempted to convert the column type to VARCHAR(MAX) in my query but still getting the error.

Here is my code:

```
SELECT patientname, IntervalName1, IntervalName2, IntervalName3
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT 
               patientname,
               CAST(IntervalName AS VARCHAR(MAX)),
               'IntervalName' +
                CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
                    (PARTITION BY patientname
                         ORDER BY patientname) AS VARCHAR(10)) AS ColumnSequence
          FROM vwPatientPEIOutcomes
         WHERE [ vwPatientPEIOutcomes.DueDate = daterange ]
         GROUP BY patientname, IntervalName
         ORDER BY patientname, ColumnSequence) Temp
PIVOT(
      MAX(patientname) FOR 
         ColumnSequence IN ( IntervalName1, IntervalName2, IntervalName3 )
     ) tb2
```

**Here are my second set of edits below in regards to your answer. I'm new to this so took my some time to figure out what was needed:**

Thank you for the answer. I was using the group by because the row_number was creating duplicates and I could not figure out how else to not have that happen.

Both the patient name and interval name are strings in the database. Intervalname is a field that signifies if they have been administered a questionnaire in a given timeframe. I'm trying to create a single row per patient.

Here is the dataset:

```
CREATE TABLE vwPatientPEIOutcomes (
  patientname varchar(max) NOT NULL,
  intervalname varchar(max) NOT NULL,
  ) ;
   INSERT INTO vwpatientPEIOutcomes (patientname,intervalname) 
  VALUES
  ('Patient 1','End'),
  ('Patient 2','Start'),
  ('Patient 3','Start'),
  ('Patient 4','End'),
  ('Patient 4','6-Month'),
  ('Patient 4','Start'),
  ('Patient 5','6-Month'),
  ('Patient 6','Start'),
  ('Patient 6','End'),
  ('Patient 7','6-Month');
```

And I'm trying to get this result:

| patientname | Intervalname1 | Intervalname2 | Intervalname3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Patient 1 | End |  |  |
| Patient 2 | Start |  |  |
| Patient 3 | Start |  |  |
| Patient 4 | End | 6-Month | Start |
| Patient 5 | 6-Month |  |  |
| Patient 6 | End | Start |  |
| Patient 7 | 6-Month |  |  |

Comment: Thanks for the welcome. I updated my answer based on (new information, new requests, clarifications)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *Conditional Aggregation* after deriving ordinal values for each interval through use of `ROW_NUMBER()` window function within a subquery such as

```sql
SELECT patientname, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN intervalname END) AS intervalname1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN intervalname END) AS intervalname2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN intervalname END) AS intervalname3
  FROM
  ( SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY patientname
                                      ORDER BY patientname) AS rn
      FROM vwPatientPEIOutcomes ) AS p
 GROUP BY patientname
 ORDER BY patientname
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f070655b63e98d7650c5d019378724f1)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

The SQL engine is probably complaining about the reference in the `GROUP BY` clause.  Change that to

```
GROUP BY patientname, CAST(IntervalName as varchar(max))
```

although, it's odd that you're using `GROUP BY` when there is no aggregation.

And I'm not sure the widow function you're using is in the correct context.  The `ORDER BY` doesn't seem meaningful.

I could be sure if you had posted code to produce the table and sample data.

Comment: Question was edited to provide with more information

Comment: I don't see CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements

Comment: I have provided the statements