# Redshift - Unsupported PIVOT column type: text

Tags: pivot, amazon-redshift

I had a look at this topic: [ERROR: Unsupported PIVOT column type: text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71958761/error-unsupported-pivot-column-type-text) but unfortunately it didn't provide me with an answer.

I have a simple table that looks like the following:

```
user_id | type | reminder_type | sent_at
----------------------------------------------------
user_a  | MID  | REMINDER_1    | 2022-02-01 15:00:00
user_a  | MID  | REMINDER_2    | 2022-02-15 06:00:00
```

Then I try to perform this query:

```sql
SELECT
  *
FROM table
PIVOT (
  MIN(sent_at) FOR reminder_type IN('REMINDER_1', 'REMINDER_2')
)
```

In order to get the following result:

```
user_id | type | reminder_1          | reminder_2
----------------------------------------------------------
user_a  | MID  | 2022-02-01 15:00:00 | 2022-02-15 06:00:00
```

And it gives me the aforementioned error: [image]

Can't get my head wrapped around it and AWS documentation doesn't provide any details about the error

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The column `reminder_type` was a result of `REGEXP_REPLACE` that resulted in type `VARCHAR(101)`.

Suddenly it worked when I explicitly cast the column to `VARCHAR`

`REGEXP_REPLACE(remin_type, '<regex>', '') AS reminder_type` doesn't work

`REGEXP_REPLACE(remin_type, '<regex>', '')::VARCHAR AS reminder_type` works perfectly